# Changing the name of the Craft folder when placed above the webroot?

Tags: install

Can you change the name of the Craft folder? I run several sites on a VPS and to place the Craft folder above the webroot, means that it sits in the User Directory, which has multiple domains running and potentially more domains could run Craft CMS and therefor the Craft folder(s) would conflict if they are all placed in the User Directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change the name of the `craft` folder. In the `index.php` file in the `public` folder update the path for the `craft` folder in the `$craftPath` variable. I use the following naming scheme for my sites:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../craft-domainname';
```

So my server directory looks something like this:

```
/(server-root)
  --craft-domain1
  --craft-domain2
  --craft-domain3
  --public_html
    --domain1
    --domain2
    --domain3
```

I keep the name `craft` in my folder structure but you don’t need to. I just do so it groups all the Craft installations together.